# Recorder with Google Speech to text

Tags: android, audio

I use google Speech to text Api in Android App , wat I want is to can record what the user says while using google speech to text in same time , and save his record 
any ideas how can do this ? or technology ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Last time I checked it was only possible to have one recorder instance active on most Android devices. I'm assuming that the speech-to-text functionality records audio, so doing any additional recording at the same time would be impossible.

Comment: well I think i Reached to a solution , thanks for your care :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still struggling with this, I have implemented something similar so what i do is, send raw byte data for google speech to text and at the same time write it to a file also to get a wav audio file at the end